# How to access the attribute of XML tags in Dynamic reports

Tags: xml, automated-tests, xmldatasource, dynamic-reports

I'm using Dynamic reports to generate my reports for which testing generated XML file is datasource .

this is my XML snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="1" failed="2" total="3" passed="0">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Default suite" duration-ms="61" started-at="2015-01-14T09:06:00Z" finished-at="2015-01-14T09:06:00Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="Default test" duration-ms="61" started-at="2015-01-14T09:06:00Z" finished-at="2015-01-14T09:06:00Z">
      <class name="TestScript.SampleTest">
        <test-method status="FAIL" signature="testMethodOne()[pri:0, instance:TestScript.SampleTest@15ee671]" name="testMethodOne" duration-ms="29" started-at="2015-01-14T14:36:00Z" finished-at="2015-01-14T14:36:00Z">
          <exception class="java.lang.AssertionError">
            <message>
              <![CDATA[expected [true] but found [false]]]>
            </message>
            <full-stacktrace>
```

---

In my reports I want the following

```
1) suite name 
2) class name 
3) method name 
4) status(pass/fail)
```

Can anyone help me out in this please?